# OpenCart3 Order Status coming as Missing Status

Tags: opencart, checkout, orders, opencart-3

I am using OpenCart version 3.0.3.2. The OpenCart *Order Status* is coming through as *Missing Orders*. What causes this issue, and how do I fix it?

The below screenshot shows the *Order Status* messages in context:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Missing Order* status is system specific instrument for regulation of payment statuses.

On the checkout page, when you come to the step five *Payment* - OpenCart generate the order in database with status of 0 (Missing Order), because when user make payment - the order_id will go to payment gateway website to maintain the payment. Once payment will be successfully processed (or else) - then payment system returns payment status and OpenCart update your order status 0 (Missing Order) to *in-progress*.

So if any user come to checkout & goes to confirm section but didn't make the payment - the order will  stay with status *Missing Order*.

You should check:

1. May be, your payment method returns status incorrect, or not returning them at all. In that case - thy to test another payment module.
2. In your payment modules there could be setting for order status. Check them to. You will find payments in *Extensions - Extensions - Payments.*

**UPDATED**

The PayPal payments have this issue very often. Found the solution here.
[How to Solve Opencart Paypal Standard Missing Orders](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26200161/3187127)

*but the first thing that comes to mind is that maybe OpenCart is using IPN to update orders in the system. If you have IPN enabled on your sandbox account but not on your live account that could cause such a problem. Login to your live PayPal profile and go to Instant Payment Notification Preferences. Make sure it's enabled.* [Drew Angell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1188826/drew-angell)

Comment: Thanks. For the info. I checked the payment status is set as pending in module settings from admin. the first point is valid by default it is missing status if payment is to yet done. but currently the transaction is done successfully and payment is received onto paypal. still the status is not changed . Seems like he response received is 0. Please help. do i reach out to Paypal?

Comment: May be there are no response at all. Are you using standard Paypal moule? What Opencart version do you use? Can you attach a link to you website?

Comment: https://saddlemen.com/  It is PayPal Payflow Pro iFrame module

Comment: Oh, may be it is because of **kbblocker**. The back request form Paypal simply blocked.

Comment: Try to use standard paypal module as experiment and see whats happens. With and without **kbblocker**

Comment: I am a developer i have no access to clients paypal account. can you elaborate more on kbblocker? is this something form Paypal accounts side?. Please note the transaction happens successfully and lands me to thank you page on opencart.

Comment: When i tried to connect to this site - i'v been redirected ot */index.php?route=kbblocker/kbblocker* page, with message "You have been blocked". Maybe, when paypel returns it status (with 99% possibility, over http/https) - it gets blocked either. You can try to disable  "Blocker" extension and try to checkout via paypal.

Comment: I looked into module and i see there is one module Knowband Blocker v1.3. . but i see two entries. Do you fall in any of these two countries? https://www.screencast.com/t/QpDCUw4bfR

Comment: I tried to disable the KBblocker module and do checkout its still same status

Comment: Ukraine. Yeah. Ok, maybe this module is not the case. Try to configure standard Paypal module and test it, for status correct changing. It may be the "PayPal Payflow Pro iFrame" works not so good as should be, because of an iframe or any other module issue.

Comment: https://www.screencast.com/t/wi5y298dKv i tried to enable the expresscheckout and it gave me this error. The details pre-populated. seems like already configured my clients account.

Comment: Haven't work with thet module yet. Could you try a standard Paypal payment?

Comment: I tried with PayPal Payments Standard and it processed successfully but gave same missing status . Please help. Is this something that shows i need to get back to paypal?

Comment: It's usually a problem with IPN from paypal not getting to your site. You can look at your IPN history in your PayPal account. This may help you find out why the message was not getting through.

It can also be the case that the IPN is delayed. I seen them take several hours to get through. Until your site receives the IPN the order will not be active.

Comment: It could be any number of things, but the first thing that comes to mind is that maybe OpenCart is using IPN to update orders in the system. If you have IPN enabled on your sandbox account but not on your live account that could cause such a problem. Login to your live PayPal profile and go to Instant Payment Notification Preferences. Make sure it's enabled.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am sure client will not provide me the paypal access. ill have to brief him about this  and ask for more detail what he sees on settings on IPN end.. But will surely get back to you if you if furthur questions.

Comment: Client checked with Paypal and they said that everything is working correctly from their end and that payments are being accepted and information returned correctly. Find attached the ipn details for your transaction.

Comment: If everything is correct from the Paypal side and they declare that there is no developers mode on - so i guess, the problem somewhere around the Opencart side. You should read error logs after the checkout. But i still think there is something is missing in Paypal settings form the client side. And try to google "opencart paypal missing order" - there are e lot of different cases. If nothing will help - you can contact me via email from my profile, and we will try to solve the problem together.

Comment: Thanks verymuch Following up on email.